# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithShrinkResForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After updating AS to 3.1.2 I'm facing a lot of problems and one of them is

`Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithShrinkResForDebug`.

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithShrinkResForDebug'.   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) `Caused by:
>   org.gradle.tooling.BuildException     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:133)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:110)
>     at
>   kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt$onEach$1.invoke(_Sequences.kt:1260)
>     at
>   kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:149)
>     at
>   kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:109)
>     at
>   kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:133)
>     at
>   kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:153)
>     at
>   kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:633)
>     at
>   kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:663)
>     at
>   kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:654)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.transform(BuildElements.kt:140)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.into(BuildElements.kt:115)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElementActionScheduler.into(BuildElementActionScheduler.kt:32)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ShrinkResourcesTransform.transform(ShrinkResourcesTransform.java:241)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>     ... 33 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer$UsageVisitor.handleCodeConstant(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1721)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer$UsageVisitor.access$000(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1602)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer$UsageVisitor$1.visitLdcInsn(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1618)
>     at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer.recordClassUsages(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1417)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer.recordClassUsages(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1381)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer.recordClassUsages(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1375)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer.recordClassUsages(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1375)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer.recordClassUsages(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1375)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer.recordClassUsages(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1375)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer.recordClassUsages(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1375)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer.recordClassUsages(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:1375)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceUsageAnalyzer.analyze(ResourceUsageAnalyzer.java:272)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ShrinkResourcesTransform.splitAction(ShrinkResourcesTransform.java:306)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ShrinkResourcesTransform.lambda$transform$0(ShrinkResourcesTransform.java:239)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:121)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

Comment: Restart IDE and clen-Rebuild

Comment: Already tried this but it didn't work out for me :(

Comment: @wookupmaker Did you find any proper solution or cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check, if you have added any .9 batch (e.g: abc.9.png) image file in resource folder, which is not an actual .9 batch image.
Include a valid .9 batch image.